# How to override website block of Safari Paste function

Tags: safari, overriding, clipboard

Some websites are now blocking command/v functions.  Firefox provides an override (about:config dom.devent.clipboardevents.enabled FALSE) to prevent websites from screwing with browser functionality.

Can Safari be configured similarly?
This is important because long hashed passwords are more important than ever in systems security and the only practical way to use them is to use keepass/1password or similar which will permit the use of one very strong password and a password generator to randomize specific site pws.  The web programmers are oblivious to the risk of not allowing this and forcing users to use weak rememberable passwords because we cannot copy/paste sophisticated long complex randomly generated passwords, and this feature will severely weaken security.